# Parsing data to get 3 different values to be stored in 3 different variables

Tags: c#, sql, parsing

I am trying to retrieve a value from a SQL database to increase version numbers. The value is string but I need to parse out the .'s and store the values in int form variables that I am using to create a new version number. ex. 11.0.0.2 I need the 0 the 0 the 2 to be stored in variables. How do I go about doing that I have done it with one variable before but not three? Here is how I parsed the first one. Here are also the variables they need to go in.

```
string[] s = cmboBoxPreviousVersion.Items[cmboBoxPreviousVersion.SelectedIndex].ToString().Split(' ');
int id;

SelectedVersion.FormatID = Convert.ToInt32(s[0]);
SelectedVersion.load();

string oldPath = lblBrowseName.Text;
string newpath = @"C:\Users\Public\Labels\";
int labelcode = Convert.ToInt32(SelectedVersion.FormatID);
int v1 = 0;
int v2 = 0;
int v3 = 1;
```

They are in the same class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class instead of writing code.

It was designed for parsing and comparing version numbers.

You could either do something like this

```
string versionText = "11.1.2.3" ;
Version versionNumber = new Version( versionText ) ;
```

Or use `Version.TryParse()`, if you want to control how invalid data is dealt with:

```
string versionText = "11.1.2.3" ;
Version versionNumber 
bool parsedOk = Version.TryParse(versionText,out versionNumber) ;
```

Comment: No it is not! It is a perfectly valid answer. This is exactly what the Version class was created for.

Comment: Then you should think again. Now it started to seem to be an answer.

Comment: I'm marking the flags on this as INVALID since it ***is an answer***, and one worthy of an upvute. "Anything that gets the user going in the right direction". Flaggers, please see [answer] for details.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading this right you are wanting to take a string like "11.0.0.2" to an array of ints {11, 0, 0, 2};

This can easily be done using `split` and and `select`.

```
string version = "11.0.0.2";
IEnumerable<int> numbers = version.Split('.').Select(int.Parse);
```

Edit as Mitch said you can just use version to make this even easier.

```
Version versionNumber = new Version("11.0.0.2");
```

Here is what the fields get filled with in this case

[image]